# MassTransit and RabbitMQ, make queue survive restart when using DI

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, servicebus, masstransit

I'm trying to force the RabbitMQ queues to survive the Rabbit service restart, while forcing them to reuse the same name after the service restart is completed.

We are using our DI container to pass the message consumers

```
return new List<Type>
{
    typeof(Consumer1), typeof(Consumer2), typeof(Consumer3), typeof(Consumer4)
};
```

That collection is then passed to the configuration via

```
t => _kernel.Get(t));
```

And then registering them this way

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, e =>
{
    foreach (var type in consumerTypes)
    {
        e.Consumer(type, getConsumer);
    }
});
```

This makes the queue to be recreated at every restart, with a GUID in the name.

If we try to do this:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, e =>
{
    foreach (var type in consumerTypes)
    {
        e.Consumer(type, getConsumer);
        e.Durable = true;
        e.AutoDelete = false;
    }
});
```

Then the queue is durable, but is not created upon service restart.

How can we specify a queue name for each consumer?

Comment: Queues are created per endpoint. Nothing stops you from having one endpoint per consumer. What is your container? MassTransit supports nearly all containers that exist.

Comment: Correct. We are using Unity, we would like to create queues naming them server1name_MessageType1, server1name_MessageType2, server2name_MessageType1, server2name_MessageType2 and making the queues do not get deleted and allowing them to store the messages until they are consumer

Comment: Receiving endpoint queues, exchanges and bindings are never deleted. I assume you figured out what I meant, looking at your answer.

Comment: Actually the queues were being deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved doing this:

```
foreach (var type in consumerTypes)
{
    var consumerType = type;
    var queueName = string.Format("{0}_{1}",
        Environment.MachineName, consumerType.ToString());
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, queueName,
        e =>
        {
            e.Consumer(consumerType, getConsumer);
        });
}
```